# Visual Studio - Filter exceptions from debug output

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, filter

I have some code that causes a bunch of exceptions (which can safely ignored) but it floods my debug output window. It always has the same form and would be easy to filter out. How do i write a macro(?) to filter out these lines in realtime

Comment: Why is your code generating exceptions that can be ignored? That suggests you are using them for normal control flow?

Comment: @MitchWheat: suppose you use dynamic objects, in that case on each access a RuntimeBinderException is thrown. Also, the .NET runtime throws and catches exceptions that it can deal with, which may flood the output window too. This is particularly apparent when running an ASP.NET web site.

Comment: @Abel: 4 years late, and I'm pretty sure that's not why the original poster (who is long since deleted) asked the question.

Comment: @MitchWheat: I know, and I understand, I just wanted to point out that there are use-cases where filtering debug output can be beneficial.

Answer (score 35):

Right click in the Output Window (when it's active), and uncheck "Exception Messages".